# Only one time click on datepicker td is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i select a date the below function just works one time:

```
$('.left').datepicker().find('td').click(function()
{
  alert("clicked");
});
```

What should i do so that if i click again on any `td`, this alert works?

Comment: Listen to `datepicker`-related events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onSelect` event fires whenever a data is selected, all the available events and methods are described in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

```
$('.left').datepicker({
    onSelect : function() {
        alert('date selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it (I've never tried it):

```
$('.left').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
    $(this).find('td').click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```